# Can you limit which MAAS nodes can be used as part of a juju environment?

Tags: juju, maas

As examples, either based on node name or on system requirements?

Answer (score 3):

MAAS accepts one constraint: "name" (for the machine's hostname).  Use that to tell MAAS which machine you want it to allocate for you.